# Ryan Fait custom HTML form and newly added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input

I'm using this script to style checkboxes and radiobuttons and it works fine:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

The problem is when I add checkboxes and radiobuttons dinamically to the page using jquery. These newly created items don't get styled.

Does anyone know a way around this?

EDIT:
I'm adding the new checkboxes dynamically using this:

```
dropdown.change(function () {
    $('#template').tmpl(data).appendTo('.container'); //here the new elements get added
    Custom[init](); //THIS DOESN'T TRIGGER
});
```

Comment: Show your jQuery. You're probably creating the elements without the correct class.

Comment: I think the problem is that the Ryan's script was not designed to work with dynamically created tags..

Comment: From what I can see, Ryan's script only looks for elements with a specific class and applies CSS to them. Show your code if you want the question to be answered.

Comment: that's correct. but my elements get created after Ryan's script load's at start and that's why they don't get styled. maybe there is a way of forcing Ryan's script to run again after the newly added elements are created?

Comment: (I'll show my code if necessary - it's just too long and really not relevant)

Comment: When you add a new element, run `Custom.init`

Comment: yeah I tried "Custom.init" but for some reason is not triggering...

Comment: Try `Custom[init]();`

Comment: that doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: Well I can't help any more then... Would need to see code because I'm swinging in the dark.

Comment: I mean't that the Custom[init](); doesn't get triggered - I added some code to the question

Comment: Show an example of one of the dynamically created elements in the html. Also try running Custom[init]() in the console and see what it's doing.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined

Comment: the elements get added using  jQuery.tmpl.js and they all contain the "styled" class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Ryan's script works, but I've worked on a lot of projects that involve custom radio buttons. Typically what I do is, use CSS and set the opacity of the radio button to zero.

```
input[type='radio'] {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Next, I wrap the radio button with a span tag with a class something like .checkbox.

Now you should be easily able to attach an event to show/hide a background image.

See complete demo: http://jsfiddle.net/07x4zr79/

I'm not a big fan of using scripts to do things, when you don't.